# Animals, plants, and sleep cycles on a moon with a very long day-night cycle

Tags: internal-consistency, moons, day-night

Let’s say that this moon is about the size of Earth. Let’s say that our moon has a very long day-night cycle; about an Earth year. During night, would all plantlife die because of the lack of light? Would all creatures be migratory, traveling to wherever it’s day? How hot would it get during day, and how cold during night? Most importantly, would life even evolve on a moon like this?

Comment: Before answering the temperature questions, folks will need more info.  The ones I can think of offhand are atmospheric composition (heat retention), distance from its orbiting star, and type of star it's orbiting.  Without any other info, the only things I can suggest are plants that enter a spore state and creatures that either hibernate or migrate

Comment: Can you [edit] your post so you're asking one specific question instead of a bunch of broad questions?

Answer (score 0):

This is several questions in one but ok.

So, there is a very real problem with your question. And that is how on Earth is the Day night Cycle a Year long ? Like if the Orbit around the Main Planet is so huge that it takes a year to make it, you planet is like a lightyear away from the central star anyways. Just because the same side always faces the Main Body dosnt mean the other one just dosnt get any light.

If the moon is locked to the Planet, it will take one Rotation around the Orbit of the Moon for a Day Night Cycle. And there is just no way that takes a year. Another way might be to have the Moon Spin is just the Perfect way so that it appears to be locked to the star. Which is Highly unlikly. But could work.

So lets assume the last case. That would mean that it is a 1 Year day night cycle. I would assume that the Plants are adapted and dont just die. The wild life would probably either stay on the day side or evolve to hibernate.

The Temps are depended on every single aspect you didnt tell us. The sizes really dosnt matter but Composition of the Atmosphere, Distance to Main Body as well as the star do. The day would probably be around what you see on earth and the night maybe around -100 Degress C or so. But all the life would evolve to keep as much Energy on it so it might be a higher temp.